# Facebook analytics gather anonymous data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can I use facebook analytics to gather anonymous information about groups of people? ex: Want to see what the avg age ranges are of people attending a public event

Answer (score 0):

Facebook Analytics does allow you to see aggregated and anonymized demographic data on groups of people who use your product.

For the example you mentioned, you will not be able to see the average age ranges of people attending a public event because there is no App Event for Facebook Page Events.

See the list of pre-defined Facebook Page Events supported by Facebook Analytics [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/page-analytics). Pre-defined events and parameters for Facebook Pages is listed as Beta in the help documentation.